# terraform aws_elasticsearch_domain - if zone_awareness_enabled is false - why is zone_awareness_config taken into account and not ignored?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating a number of elasticsearch clusters in AWS using terraform. Each cluster can have a different number of instances. If there is one instance - there should be one AZ. If there are two instances - there should be two AZs. If I have one instance in my terraform aws_elasticsearch_domain resource, I set zone_awareness_enabled as false. The problem is that zone_awareness_config is not ignored as I would assume it should be. So if I have two AZs- I'd need to add the zone_awareness_config to the tf file. I'd have to manage two files.

This is the cluster_config:

```
cluster_config {
      instance_type = "c5.large.elasticsearch"
      instance_count = var.es_instance_count
      dedicated_master_enabled = var.dedicated_master_enabled
      dedicated_master_count = var.es_instance_count
      zone_awareness_enabled = var.es_instance_count > 1 ? true : false
      zone_awareness_config {
        availability_zone_count = var.es_instance_count
      }
  }
```

The cluster_config should work for 2 or 3 instances, but also for 1 instance in 1 AZ. But it doesn't. If I have 1 AZ - I have to remove the zone_awareness_config from the file.
How can I ignore the zone_awareness_config if I have 1 AZ?

Comment: What version of the AWS provider are you using?

Comment: Aws provider version is 2.27.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try make a [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) to only add the zone_awareness_config block when your instance count is greater than 1

```
dynamic "zone_awareness_config" {
  for_each = var.es_instance_count > 1 ? [var.es_instance_count] : []
  content {
    availability_zone_count = var.es_instance_count
  }
}
```

Comment: Do dynamic blocks exist in prior to terraform v0.12?

Comment: @AdilSadik No, they do not  (just adding this incase someone else lands here with the same question)

Answer (score 1):

This example isn't using the value set in the for_each loop. It really should be:

```
content {
    availability_zone_count = zone_awareness_config.value
  }
```